# Isolated singularities and tangent cones

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, singularity-theory

Assume that I have an affine hypersurface $X =V(f)\subset \mathbb{C}^4$ of degree $d$ with an *isolated* singularity of multiplicity $m$ at the origin $o=(0,0,0,0)$. Let $$f:=f_m + f_{m+1}+ \cdots +f_d$$
be the decomposition of $f$ into homogeneous pieces and suppose, in addition, that the singularity at $o$ is *ordinary*, that is the tangent cone $C=V(f_m) \subset \mathbb{C}^4$ is a cone over a *smooth* surface of degree $m$ in $\mathbb{P}^3$.

Simple examples show that, in general, the germ $(X, o)$ is *not* isomorphic to the germ $(C,  o)$. For instance, take
$$f=x_0^4+4x_0^3x_1+6x_0^2x_1^2+4x_0x_1^3+x_2^4+4x_2^3x_3+6x_2^2x_3^2+4x_2x_3^3+x_0^5+x_0x_1^4$$
$$+x_0^4x_2+7x_1^4x_2+3x_0x_2^4-x_2^5+4x_0x_3^4+11x_2x_3^4,$$
so that $$f_4=x_0^4+4x_0^3x_1+6x_0^2x_1^2+4x_0x_1^3+x_2^4+4x_2^3x_3+6x_2^2x_3^2+4x_2x_3^3.$$
Then, denoting with $\tau$ the Tjurina number, by using Singular one finds $$\tau(f, 0)=71, \quad \tau(f_4, 0)=81,$$
so the two germs are not isomorphic.
This implies that the (analytic) local rings $\mathcal{O}^{an}_{X,0}, \quad \mathcal{O}^{an}_{C,0}$
are not isomorphic, see for instance [De Jong-Pfister, Local analytic geometry, page 120].

Now my question is:

> Are at least the completed rings $\widehat{\mathcal{O}}^{an}_{X,0}, \quad \widehat{\mathcal{O}}^{an}_{C,0}$ isomorphic? If the answer is yes, what is a reference? If the answer is no, what is a counterexample?

My apologies in advance to the experts of singularity theory if this question turns out to be a trivial one.

**EDIT.** Jason Starr's comments suggest that the two completed rings should *not* be isomorphic. Let me then ask a weaker form of my question:

> **(1)** Assume that the local ring of the tangent cone at the vertex $\mathcal{O}^{an}_{C,0}$ is a UFD. Can one conclude that the same is true for $\mathcal{O}^{an}_{X,0}$?
>
> **(2)** Assume that the completed local ring of the tangent cone at the vertex $\widehat{\mathcal{O}}^{an}_{C,0}$ is a UFD. Can one conclude that the same is true for $\widehat{\mathcal{O}}^{an}_{X,0}$?

Comment: I am pretty certain that Mike Artin's theory of algebraization of formal moduli implies that the completed local rings are not isomorphic.  If the completed local rings are isomorphic, Artin proves that the Henselized local rings are isomorphic.  However, the local rings of germs of analytic functions factor through the Henselized local rings.

Comment: In previous comment: "algebraization of formal moduli" --> "approximation of complete local rings".

Comment: @Jason. Thank you very much for your comments, I will think about them. Actually, I realized that in my situation I do not really need that the two rings are isomorphic, but only that they are both UFD. I edited the question accordingly. Please be so kind and let me know if you have any reference or suggestion in that direction. 

Comment: @Francesco:  I am probably not the best person to ask.  The best result I can find is Lemme 3.16, p. 133, SGA 2, Exp. XI (immediately following Grothendieck's proof of the Samuel Conjecture).  Combined with the Rees algebra / deformation to the tangent cone (whose generic fiber, essentially, will be $X$ and whose closed fiber will be $C$), this gives the following: if $C$ is parafactorial and has depth $\geq 3$, and if also $X$ has depth $\geq 2$, then also $X$ is parafactorial.  

Comment: @Jason: Thank you, I will check this. At any rate, since $X$ and $C$ are complete intersection (hence Cohen-Macauley) of dimension $3$ the condition about depth is satisfied. Since the singularity is isolated, if I can prove that $X$ is parafactorial, it seems to me that I can conclude that it is factorial by SGA2, Exp. XI, Corollaire 3.9. Or I missing something? 

Comment: @Francesco:  I believe, in fact, that I missed something.  I did not realize you were working with local complete intersections.

Comment: I realize now that my suggestion above was based on the (wrong) assumption that parafactoriality of local rings is stable with respect to localization, just as factoriality is.  Unfortunately this is incorrect.  

Comment: Some general remark (sorry if it's trivial). For an ordinary multiple point, $(X,0)\subset(\Bbb{C}^n,0)$, i.e. precisely your case, the completions of the germs $(X,0)$, $(T_{(X,0)},0)$ are almost never isomorphic. (Due to the presence of moduli.) However, they are equisingular. (There exists a $\mu=const$ deformation from $T_{(X,0)}$ to $(X,0)$.) A simple sufficient condition for isomorphism is by checking "how far the "unnecessary" monomials" lie above the Newton diagram".

Comment: @Dmitry: thank your very much for your interesting remark. Could you please give me some reference about the equisingularity?

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi: the general bible is of course Arnol'd-Goryunov-Vassil'ev-Lyashko. You can also look in Greuel-Lossen-Shustin.  Some more details: the ordinary multiple point is a semi-homogeneous singularity (i.e. $f_p+f_{>p}$ with $\{f_p=0\}\subset\Bbb{P}(C^n)$ smooth). In particular, it is Newton-non-degenerate. For such singularities any deformation by the "upper monomials" is topologically equisingular (i.e. you can do whatever you like with $f_{>p}$).    On the other hand, if you insist the deformation to be equi-analytic, then you can deform only by the entries of the Tjurina ideal.